# Specifying which fields from an object could be obtained through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have some classes that looks like this

```
class Person {

  public String name;
  public String age;
  public String dateOfBirth;

  /* more fields */

  public String[] fieldsToReflect()
  {
     return new String[] { "name", "age"}
  }
}

class Vehicle {

  public String make;
  public String model;
  public String mileage;

  /* more fields */

  public String[] fieldsToReflect()
  {
    return new String[] { "make", "model" }
  }
}
```

`Person` objects have a number of fields, but when getting fields from instances of `Person` I only want to allow others to access `name` and `age`.

Since I may be working with arbitrary objects (eg: a `Vehicle` object), I figured the easiest way to uniformly handle all of the objects within the application is to have each object tell me what fields I can get from them.

Are there other approaches I could consider when it comes to controlling what fields should be retrieved from an object?

Comment: Others will be free to ignore the values you provide and access any attribute or method, regardless of scope.

Comment: You should use `private` & `protected` if you want to limit scope.

Comment: I'm not limiting scope. All of these fields are intended to be publicly editable by anything. It's just that when it comes to certain classes using reflection to get data, I would like to be able to say "this is the data I am willing to let you get through reflection"

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. If everything is public, then that means it can be access by any class, regardless of whether or not you are using reflection. Typically you use reflection to get methods and fields that may be hidden.

Comment: Basically I have a GUI table component that displays an object's fields, which I pick from a list of objects. The list may contain all sorts of different objects and I decided to use reflection to uniformly handle any objects in this system over other design decisions. I don't want *that* particular table to access all declared fields in a class, but I have other things that should have all access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use annotations, like

```
@ReflectableFields({"name", "age"})
class Person {

    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String dateOfBirth;

}
```

with `@ReflectableFields` defined as

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ReflectableFields {
    String[] value();
}
```

Or field by field :

```
class Person {

    @Reflectable
    public String name;

    @Reflectable
    public String age;      
    public String dateOfBirth;

}
```

with `@Reflectable` defined as

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Reflectable {
    // No field needed
}
```

The first solution is less verbose, but names in annotation have to be updated along with field names. The second solution seems more verbose, but field name don't need to be explicit.

Comment: Where can I find more information on those particular annotations?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have explain more : these would be annotation that you define yourself. I'll update my post.

Comment: ah, yes I was wondering why I couldn't find anything about them.

Comment: I have annotated a couple fields with `@Reflectable` but when I use `getDeclaredFields()` it is still grabbing all of the fields I declared in the class. Is there something else I would need to do?

Comment: Just use field.isAnnotationPresent(Reflectable.class). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#isAnnotationPresent%28java.lang.Class%29

Comment: Thanks, now it is working. I like the idea of just annotating which fields should be "reflectable" since then I don't have to duplicate any typing. The advantage of returning an array of strings would be, I guess, to specify order? Though I could just re-arrange the declarations in the class...

Comment: You're right, an array provides an order. You can't rely on field declarations ordering, since `getDeclaredFields()` is not required to have a particular order.